# Correct way of doing relationships in sequelize model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Recently we moved to Sequelize ORM from Knex due to which we have existing database to which models are map to . Everything working fine except model relationships.

So I have a users table and roles table. Each user can have one role but each role can be assigned to many users. To map these to models, I created model files that is as follows.

User Model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../utility/dbConnection');
const roles = require('./Roles');
module.exports = sequelize.define("User", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    middleName: Sequelize.STRING(255),
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING(255),

    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        unique: true
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        unique: true
    },
    is_phonenumber_verified: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        default: false
    },
    is_email_verified: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        default: false
    },

    roleID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },



    password: Sequelize.STRING(255)

    // }, {
    //     defaultScope: {
    //         attributes: { exclude: ['password'] }
    //     }
}, {
    tableName: 'users'
},{
    classMethods: {
        associate: function() {
          this.hasOne(roles,{foreignKey: 'roleID'})
        }
    }
}
 
);
```

roles Model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../utility/dbConnection');
module.exports = sequelize.define("Role", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
        unique: true
    },

},{
    tableName: 'roles'
});
```

Now in the controller file, I want to fetch user details and role name for which code snippet are as follows

```
const userModel = require('../../models/Users');
const rolesModel = require('../../models/Roles');
 let user = await userModel.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } },{include:[{model:rolesModel}]});
```

The problem is it only fetches rolesID from the Users table but not roles name from roles table .

Can anyone help me on this what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

You have To Write Your Include Condition Like This

```
const userModel = require('../../models/Users');
const rolesModel = require('../../models/Roles');
let user = await userModel.findOne({
where: {
    email: req.body.email
},include:
        [{ model: rolesModel }]
});
```

you can use `belongsTo` relation instead of using `hasOne`
add this relation in roles table and remove from users table

```
 classMethods: {
    associate: function() {
      this.belongsTo(users,{foreignKey: 'roleID'})
    }
}
```

You can see this Sequelize [Associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html) docs to know more about Associations and relations

Comment: Hey @Arya now I am getting an error `Role is not associated to User` .

Comment: It means you are on right way now you have to associate role table with user table check I have updated answer

Comment: still I am getting the same error `Role is not associated to User`